# How to add google maps to google search results?

Tags: google-maps, google-search

More and more I stumble upon such fancy search results:

https://www.google.lt/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=gaumina&oq=gaumina&aq=f&aqi=g2g-s1g1g-s1g2g-s3&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=793l1488l0l1516l7l7l0l0l0l0l150l577l4.2l6l0&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i10j0j0i10j0l2j0i10l3.793l1488l0l1517l7l7l0l0l0l0l150l577l4j2l6l0.frgbld

How to do this? Where should I add this through? Google Maps? Webmaster tools? Else?

Answer (score 0):

check out [Google Custom Search APIs and Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your business to Google Maps. Check [Google my business](https://www.google.co.in/business/) for more information.

Just make sure your NAP (Name, address, phone number) is correct and same across your sites, social networks and google maps. Google give better ranks if all the information across multiple networks are same (yes, they compare the values).